# Append multiple variables(params) to url for ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to append values from a `checked` checkbox to a url that later would be used for an ajax call. As mentioned I would only like to have the values appended to the `url` if checkbox is checked. If a user checks and then unchecks, this would indicate not to add the value to the url. Below I have some basic foundation code. How can I append multiple items to the url ?

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="item1" />
<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="item2" />
<input type="checkbox" value="3" id="item3" />
<input type="submit" id="submitForm" value="Submit Form" />
<form>

<script>
$('#submitForm').click(function() {
    $('checkbox').click(function() {
    $.getJSON('www.mysite.com/mypage.php?id='+item1+item2+item3)
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Use this: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First give your checkboxes a specific name like;

```
<form name="checkbox_form" id="checkbox_form">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="item1" name="val1" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="2" id="item2" name="val2" />
    <input type="checkbox" value="3" id="item3" name="val3" />
    <input type="submit" id="submitForm" value="Submit Form" />
<form>
```

And your js will be;

```
$('#submitForm').click(function() {
    var url = "'www.mysite.com/mypage.php";
    if ($("#checkbox_form").serialize().length > 0) {
        url += "?" + $("#checkbox_form").serialize();     
    }
    alert("Your ajax url will be: " + url);
    $.getJSON(url)
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/UKV3r/2/**

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery method serialize() as follows:

```
var query = $('form').serialize()
```

and after:

```
$.getJSON('www.mysite.com/mypage.php?'+query );
```

Only necessary to provide the input field attribute "name":

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="item1" name="item1"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="item2" name="item2"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="3" id="item3" name="item3"/>
<input type="submit" id="submitForm" value="Submit Form" />
<form>
```

and you get:

```
www.mysite.com/mypage.php?item1=1&item2=2&item3=3
```

if all checkboxes are selected.